# WebTextView cannot be cast to android.view.SurfaceView

Tags: android, webview, surfaceview

I was set SurfaceView for webview, like that:

```
wv.setOnHierarchyChangeListener(new ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener() {  
        @Override
        public void onChildViewRemoved(View parent, View child) {}
        @Override
        public void onChildViewAdded(View parent, View child) {
            if(child.getClass().getName().equals("com.adobe.flashplayer.FlashPaintSurface")){
                Log.i("flash", "surface is open");
                ((SurfaceView)child).setZOrderOnTop(false); 
                ((SurfaceView)child).dispatchWindowFocusChanged(isHidden());
        }}
    });
```

but...

When I click on WebViewText, for trying write there something my app just crash, and show that error log:

```
03-07 10:14:37.425: E/AndroidRuntime(7378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 10:14:37.425: E/AndroidRuntime(7378): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.webkit.WebTextView cannot be cast to android.view.SurfaceView
```

I was idiot - forget put brackets if(){}. Please not lower my rate!

Comment: child is not SurfaceView ... did you forget about brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing brackets after `if`...

```
wv.setOnHierarchyChangeListener(new ViewGroup.OnHierarchyChangeListener() {  
    @Override
    public void onChildViewRemoved(View parent, View child) {}
    @Override
    public void onChildViewAdded(View parent, View child) {
        if(child.getClass().getName().equals("com.adobe.flashplayer.FlashPaintSurface")) {
            Log.i("flash", "surface is open");
            ((SurfaceView)child).setZOrderOnTop(false); 
            ((SurfaceView)child).dispatchWindowFocusChanged(isHidden());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, today isn't my day!